# Android studio получить файлы скачанные на эмулятор

Tags: python, python-3.x, android-studio, appium

Я в эмуляторе скачиваю файлы (контакты), но не могу их "забрать". Не пойму, как задавать путь для скачивания или вообще, как получить файлы с эмулятора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Обычно в правом нижнему есть лежащая на боку надпись Device File Explorer (если мы говорим об Android Studio)

Кликаете на неё. Выбираете нужный **работающий** эмулятор. Дальше находите файловой системе нужные файлы.

На файле кликаете правой кнопкой. Выбираете "Save As" и сохраняете его на комп.

Comment: А не подскажете как это можно реализовать программно чтобы не руками каждый раз вытягивать?

Comment: Программно, это только работа с ADB через командную строку. Студия обычно делает то же самое, только предоставляет графический интерфейс.

Comment: Почитайте про команду adb pull. Например, здесь: http://android-tip.com/soveti_i_poleznoe/77-adb-dlya-chaynikov-chast-1.html/

Comment: За это отдельное спасибо!! Для чайников это то что надо ))